# Taking multiple orders on a Cafe program, along with a loop

Tags: python

I am currently trying to work on this python school assignment, and I'm lost at how to add a loop to continue ordering, and how to take orders of both coffee and tea. My program only lets you take an order of one, tea or coffee. My except ValueError also causes the order of adding vanilla syrup to the medium and large coffee not unique, and lets it be added to the small coffee as well, when it shouldn't. I am having a lot of trouble with this, and would really appreciate any help or suggestions to as what I could add/try

This is my code:

```
    price = 0
print("Tea is 1, Coffee is 2.")
print("Small is 1, Medium is 2, Large is 3.")

try:
  drinkchoice=float(input("What drink would you like?: "))
  if(drinkchoice == 1):
      TeaAmount=float(input("How many would you like?: "))
  else:
    CoffeeAmount=float(input("How many would you like?: "))  
except ValueError: 
    print("Error, follow the directions!")
    exit()

try:
  drinksize=float(input("What size would you like?: "))
  if(drinksize == 3 and drinkchoice == 1):
    print("1 for yes, 2 for no")
    Oprah=float(input("Would you like the Oprah sponsered option for 0.75 more?: "))
  if(drinksize == 2 or 3 and drinkchoice == 2):
    print("1 for yes, 2 for no")
    vanilla=float(input("Would you like a shot of vanilla syurp for 0.50 more?: "))
except ValueError:
   print("Error, follow the directions!")
   exit()

if(drinkchoice == 1):
  if(drinksize == 1):
    price=price+2*TeaAmount
  if(drinksize == 2):
    price=price+3.50*TeaAmount
  if(drinksize == 3):
    price=price+4.65*TeaAmount
    if(Oprah == 1):
       teaPrice=round(price,2)
       price=price+.75*TeaAmount
       OprahPrice=.75*TeaAmount
    else:
      price=round(price,2)
  coffeePrice = 0
  vanillaPrice = 0

if(drinkchoice ==2):
  if(drinksize == 1):
    price=price+2.25*CoffeeAmount
  if(drinksize == 2):
    price=price+3.75*CoffeeAmount
    if(vanilla == 1):
      coffeePrice = round(price,2)
      price=price+.50*CoffeeAmount
      vanillaPrice=.50*CoffeeAmount
    else:
      price=round(price,2)
      vanillaPrice=0
  if(drinksize == 3):
    price=price+4.85*CoffeeAmount
    if(vanilla == 1):
      coffeePrice = round(price,2)
      price=price+.50*CoffeeAmount
      vanillaPrice=.50*CoffeeAmount
    else:
      price=round(price,2)
      vanillaPrice=0
  teaPrice = 0
  OprahPrice = 0


price = round(price,2)

print("You paid $", teaPrice, "for tea")
print("You paid $", coffeePrice, "for coffee")
print("You paid $", OprahPrice, "for the extra Oprah version")
print("You paid $",  vanillaPrice, "for the vanilla syrup")
print("Your bill is $", price)
```

[Here is the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRA1U.png)

Comment: to keep ordering you can throw everything in a `while True:` loop and break when the user is done

Comment: I would suggest restructuring your code though that does not look too efficient or easy to work w/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try incorporating the while True: loop, and I'll restructure the code so it's easy to work with

Comment: yeah maybe use dictionaries for price reference and getting data from choices

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this as an answer as its too big for a comment.

With the structure of your data you will be much more suited to use a `dictionary`. This will make your code much easier to read, structure your data better and better support the addition of new drinks and new drink sizes in the future.

Dictionaries store a `key` and a `value` which can be called later by `dict[key]` or `dict.get(key)`.

An example of storing this data could be;

```
drinks = {'tea': {'small': 1, 'medium': 2, 'large': 3}}
```

Now when a user specifies what they want, your life and code becomes much easier to manage and understand.

```
drinks['tea']['small']
#1
```

However, if `tea` does not exist, this method of calling your key, value pair would return a `KeyError`, so it may be better to use `get()` instead.

```
drinks.get('tea', {}).get('small')
#1
```

In the case either key here does not exist, this line will return `None` which provides a safe method to call your values.

You can also store your `drink_options` in a dictionary too. When you need to change pricing, just change the value of the key pair in your dict.

For your looping, `while True:` is a good way to continually loop until a user specifies to stop. It needs to be noted though, if you do not break out of this loop, it would run indefinitely.

You can use `break` to exit your `while` loop.

Below you can find some links on some reading which may help you learn more relating to this assignment. Happy learning!

Links

---

[Python Official Documentation - Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

[Python Official Documentation - Break & continue statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

[While Loops](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/)

[Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try adding that into my program when I rewrite it. Seems like it'll definitely help

Comment: Quick question if you could answer, would this allow an efficient loop?                                    n = 5
>>> while n > 0: I then will ask the user if they are done ordering, and if yes then n = 6, breaking the loop? If not, I will keep n = 5 and they can continue to order

Comment: You can always just do a `run = True` and `while run:` then set `run` to `False` when you want to break. If not just call `break` from your while loop.